# How can i get event.path in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

How can i get event path in ie?

For example we have the next code:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  console.log(event.path);
  // In chrome => [element,...]
  // In IE => undefined
})
```

How can I get event path in IE?

Answer (score 1):

The `path` is a non standard feature which may not have wide support especially in older browsers / ie browsers

Comment: Is there another methods to do this?

Comment: Not that easy. I would rather concentrate on modern browsers.

Comment: Event.path is not supported by MS Edge and IE. You can verify this from this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath I did not get any other way to get event.path for IE.